# Error detecting Nodejs when trying to install "Codux" on windows

Tags: node.js, terminal

While trying to install Codux (https://www.codux.com) on Windows 10, I am facing this issue where it says: **"node -v" failed with error**. I have node v19.4.0 installed. Can you kindly help me understand what might be causing the issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codux is querying for the node version using cmd.exe (Command Prompt)
when executed on Windows.
Can you please check whether executing node -v
in Command Prompt returns the same version as PowerShell?
It can be
launched via opening the Start Menu and typing "command prompt" in the
search.

In addition, could you clarify how was Node.js installed? was it via the official installer, or perhaps nvm for windows?

For followup, we suggest you join us on Discord at: https://discord.gg/fg3Ywsa44N
Or you could contact our support at: https://help.codux.com/kb/en/contact

Thanks in advance,
The Codux Team

Comment: Using nvm to install the lts version and exporting node to path manually fixed the issue.